# Windows Equivalent of the 'head -c' command

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a unix command that does the following:

```
head -c 2048 > test.txt
```

basically its taking first 2kb of the test.txt file.

Can we do something similar in windows cmd prompt?

Comment: thank you guys for all your awesome replies..@sonjz I have a text file with one long string of hex dump..how can i use your code to extract only 2kb worth of data from it?? I tried your code but its still extracting the whole hex dump..thanks..i will upload the text file file for you..

Comment: please find the link here-> https://www.dropbox.com/s/h29mdg0t8df8i1e/test.txt?dl=0

Comment: @ sonjz: how to use "Get-FileHex" to extract 2kb of hex data using powershell..do you know about this function??

Comment: you want to extract byte array.  The following code will yank 2KB and write to a new file: $byteArray = Get-Content binary.bin -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 2KB; [io.file]::WriteAllBytes('c:\binary.bin', $byteArray)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simplifying this answer because of @chubbsondubs' comment.

`-TotalCount` will count lines if reading in text, so always force it to read the file as bytes, then the `-TotalCount` will only refer to bytes and you can get an account count.

```powershell
Get-Content test.txt -Encoding byte -TotalCount 2KB | Set-Content test1.txt -Encoding byte
```

More information here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888063/powershell-to-get-the-first-x-mb-of-a-file

Comment: This gets the first 2048 lines not bytes of the file.  TotalCount takes the number of lines you want.

Comment: @chubbsondubs yup, i see the issue now, you always have to encode and decode in bytes, i'll update the answer

Comment: this is not the command prompt, its powershell

Comment: Question was for "command line", both command prompt and PowerShell are command line shells for Windows.  Command prompt being the archaic "stop using this" one.

Comment: This doesn't work in Powershell 6. In order for it to work, you must replace `-Encoding byte` with `-AsByteStream`

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell you can't print out by size in a native way; there is the [`type`](https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat) command which will output a whole text file, but you can't specify how much you want to output.

There is also the `more` command, which will allow you to print out lines of a file. These are some of the flags from `more /?`:

```
/E      Enable extended features
/C      Clear screen before displaying page
/P      Expand FormFeed characters
/S      Squeeze multiple blank lines into a single line
/Tn     Expand tabs to n spaces (default 8)

        Switches can be present in the MORE environment
        variable.

+n      Start displaying the first file at line n

files   List of files to be displayed. Files in the list
        are separated by blanks.

If extended features are enabled, the following commands
are accepted at the -- More -- prompt:

P n     Display next n lines
S n     Skip next n lines
F       Display next file
Q       Quit
=       Show line number
?       Show help line
<space> Display next page
<ret>   Display next line
```

If neither of these work for you, you can alternatively install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and you can use `cat` or `head`.

Comment: cygwin also has the 'head' command if you choose to use that option

Comment: @JeffClayton Shoot.. you're right, for some reason I was thinking cat instead of head

Comment: 'cat' is the unix command that matches up to the 'type' command in windows, since you were discussing 'type' it only makes sense.

Comment: Question is asking to process *bytes* in file, not *lines*

Answer (score 2):

To keep first 2048 bytes of test.txt:

```
FSUTIL file seteof test.txt 2048
```

To keep a copy of test.txt, make a copy of it first.
Much faster than piped powershell commands, as in the selected answer; works at OS file system level.

Tested in Win 10

Comment: limitation: does not work with streams like stdin